# Image matching or image hashing or image segmentation with DL

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, fast-ai

I have set of images different sizes like 1024, 2048 , 4056 and different resolutions and magnificent saved in one folder. I have other set of image with very low resolution and of size 1024.
What I want to do is when I give low res image as input to model , it's should give me all matching high res images from the folder.
I appreciate any kind of suggestions in using methods or models to be approached .

Thank You in advance

Comment: It depends how you will define a match between images. Would you mind sharing more on that? Should those low-res images be the exactly same images but with different resolution?

Comment: Yes , they are same images with diff resolutions

Comment: Then CNN could be an option for you since after rescaling both of those images (high and low res) will produce similar output feature vectors.

Comment: Thank You for your response @artem ignatovich. Could you plz help me to start with. I need the output such as for each low resolution image , the model should be able to give all matching high resolution, diff magn images.